# how to get a pre-authenticated URL to a Sharepoint document?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, nodejs

I'm using the Sharepoint REST API server-side to browse through documents, that works.

For authentication (having login credentials known server-side) I use [node-sp-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sp-auth) which provides me a **FedAuth** cookie that I can use in server-side REST requests.

I would like to allow my users to download/display PDF documents. Is there a way I can use a pre-authenticated URL **client-side** so that the web browser accesses the document *directly* from the Sharepoint domain?

I mean, the user uses my site `someservice.com`, which already knows login credentials specific to that user. The site is meant to provide easier access to some Sharepoint site.  By navigating
`someservice.com`  he becomes interested in `somedocument.pdf` (stored on Sharepoint) and would like to display it. I'm looking for some way that the user's browser can *directly access* `https://othersite.sharepoint.com/site/whatever/somedocument.pdf`. He needs to authenticate for that URL but he is lacking the Auth cookie, which is only known server-side.

I can think of two theoretical solutions:

- The server shares the auth cookie with the web client. That would be no problem in terms of disclosure, but `someservice.com` obviously can't set a cookie for a `othersite.sharepoint.com`.
- I request server-side a pre-authenticated URL from Sharepoint (with some sort of hash added, for example), which allows direct access to that specific file for a short amount of time.

Is something like that possible with Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand the question correctly, but why aren't you serving the pdf document through your own server?. That server, having a connection to SP can easily retrieve the document

Comment: Yes, that would be possible (it would act as sort of a proxy), but I'd like to avoid that extra load on the server (including  [HTTP range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) handling etc.) - if possible

Comment: You would de-complicate the scenario if you did copy them to a non-SPO service. You can do something like use Power Automate to copy to Azure Blob Storage when a file is created/updated in a SharePoint Doc Lib. You can then reference the ABS URL for your external user. You can also front ABS with Azure CDN for better perf than what SPO could give you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Azure B2B or B2C? User is already auth'ed, you can integrate the sign up process with SPO sharing/adding the user to an Azure Security Group that has access to the documents in SPO.

Or copy those docs to Azure Blob Storage and serve them from there.

Comment: The SharePoint installation is out of my control. I'm just consuming it's API.

Comment: Sure, it is SPO per how you wrote your post. But you can have an Azure security group added to the appropriate location(s) in SharePoint, perform B2B/B2C invites and add the user to the security group. This can be done programmatically using the Graph APIs.

Comment: A standard Sharepoint User can do that? Can you point me to some document where I can learn more about it? I'm not very familiar with SharePoint and those terms unfortunately don't tell me very much.